# Firemonkey Windows/iOS compatible code

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, multiplatform

I am trying to run my app, written in Firemonkey, on iOS.
I was read this http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop but i mean that it's not all :-/

I have this procedure

```
procedure generateData(Var OutVar:String;DataText:String);
var
  S: TBytes;
  StreamInput, StreamOutput: TMemoryStream;
  // String to TBytes
  function UTF8Bytes(const s: UTF8String): TBytes;
  begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(s));
    {$IFDEF IOS} // iOS strings are 0 based but hor about retyped ???
    // this ?
    if Length(Result)>0 then Move(s[0], Result[0], Length(s)-1);
    // or this ?
    //if Length(Result)>0 then Move(s[0], Result[0], Length(s));
    // or this ?
    //if Length(Result)>0 then Move(s[1], Result[0], Length(s));
    {$ELSE} // Win strings are 1 based
    if Length(Result)>0 then Move(s[1], Result[0], Length(s));
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
begin
  StreamInput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  StreamOutput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  S := UTF8Bytes(DataText);

  {$IFDEF IOS} // What about TBytes? They are different too ?
  // this ?
  //StreamInput.Write(S[0], Length(S)-1);
  // or this ?
  StreamInput.Write(S[0], Length(S));
  {$ELSE}
  StreamInput.Write(S[1], Length(S));
  {$ENDIF}

  StreamInput.Position := 0;

  MyCryptoStreamFunction(StreamInput, StreamOutput);
  StreamOutput.Position := 0;

  SetLength(S, StreamOutput.Size);
  {$IFDEF IOS}
  // this ?
  StreamOutput.Read(S[0], StreamOutput.Size);
  // or this ?
  //StreamOutput.Read(S[0], StreamOutput.Size-1);
  // this will raise exception and kill app
  //StreamOutput.Read(S[1], StreamOutput.Size);
  {$ELSE}
  StreamOutput.Read(S[1], StreamOutput.Size);
  {$ENDIF}
  OutVar := StringReplace(EncodeBase64(S,Length(S)), sLineBreak, '',[rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

on windows works normally but on ios this code `StreamOutput.Read(S[1], StreamOutput.Size);` raise exception and kill my app.

Can anyone help what of code variant in {$IFDEF IOS} is equal to code in {ELSE}
by their functionality?

Comment: Use `Low(s)` to get the start index for all platforms. `Length` is the same for all platforms (note that unicode characters are of Size(Char)). `TBytes` is a dynamic byte array, always indexed from zero.

Comment: Why do you need all this anyway? Can't you just use `TEncoding.UTF8` to read and write your strings?

Comment: Use low like this `StreamInput.Write(S[Low(s)], Length(S));` ?

Comment: Yes but consider that the length of a unicode string is twice the size in bytes. `Length(S)*SizeOf(Char)`.

Comment: Then this code for Windows `if Length(Result)>0 then Move(s[1], Result[0], Length(s));` is equal
 to this `if Length(Result)>0 then Move(s[Low(s)], Result[0], Length(s)*SizeOf(Char));` and the second can be used on Win and iOS?  And the same situation is here `StreamInput.Write(S[1], Length(S));` = `StreamInput.Write(S[Low(S)], Length(S)*SizeOf(Char));`  and here `StreamOutput.Read(S[1], StreamOutput.Size);` = `StreamOutput.Read(S[[Low(S)], StreamOutput.Size*SizeOf(Char));` ?

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you,  in the `Utf8Bytes()` function, the string is `Utf8`, where the each character are `AnsiChar`, i.e. size = 1 byte.  My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Low(s)` to get the first index of the string for all platforms:

```
// utf8 string to TBytes
function UTF8Bytes(const s: UTF8String): TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  if (Length(s) > 0) then
    Move(s[Low(s)],Result[0],Length(s));
end;
```

The line `S := UTF8Bytes(DataText);` implicitly converts the unicode string  `DataText` to an utf8 string before entering the function.

`TBytes` is dynamic byte array. All dynamic arrays are zero based.

```
StreamInput.Write(S[0],Length(S));
```

---

Using [System.UTF8Encode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UTF8Encode) is an alternate way to convert a unicode string to an utf8 byte array:

```
procedure UTF8Encode(const US: UnicodeString; var B: array of Byte);
```